# Facebook post JSON "data-ft" data

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was browsing source code from a facebook post and I found a paramaeter in its "data-ft" , while I understand many of the present in JSON. I do NOT have a clue what qid is used for.

For ex.:
<< data-ft= [qid 5974492283807537878 >>

Did anyone had an experience with this mystical parameter ? I wonder why fb included it.

P.S. : You can reproduce this scenario by just looking the source code of any fb post and search for "qid" without quotes. I can include here full code, if any-body is interested.

Comment: Can you show more sample code? Where/how exactly did you get this from?

Comment: You can reproduce this scenario by just looking the source code of any fb post[made by YOU] and search for "qid" without quotes.